# Problems with for and while loop in data frame

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Can you explain me my mistake in my loops

Data set is like this

```
    plot<-c("A", "B", "C")
    s<-c(0.3, 0.7, 0.6)
    pe<-c(0.7, 0.3, 0.4)

    a<-data.frame(plot, s, pe)

library(reshape)
a.long<-melt(a, id=c("plot")
a.long1<-a.long[order(a.long$plot, -a.long$value),]
```

And now my two loops which are not working

```
    a.long1$maxS<-0
while (i <= length(a.long1$plot)+1){
    if (a.long1$plot[i]==a.long1$plot[i+1]){
    a.long1$maxS[i]<-1
    } else {
      a.long1$maxS[i]<-0
    }
   i = i+ 1
  }
```

and

```
for (i in 1:length(a.long1$plot)){
  if (a.long1$plot[i] == a.long1$plot[i+1] ) {
    a.long1$maxS[i]=1
  } else { 
  a.long1$maxS[i]=0}
}
```

I understand the mistake I make that this statement `a.long1$plot[i] == a.long1$plot[i+1]` NA value at the end of the data but I can't make it to work, even though tried for hours.

Comment: Please avoid to assign values to `plot`, as it is a built-in function.

Comment: I changed variable's name but still receive that:
Error in if (a.long1$plotek[i] == a.long1$plotek[i + 1]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: A closing bracket is missing here: `a.long<-melt(a, id=c("plot")`. `i` is not defined for the `while` statement, thus it is not reproducible. In the `for` loop, `i` must be between 1 and 5, if you want it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't explain the expected output, but I guess you want this:

```
a.long1$maxS <- as.numeric(c(head(a.long1$plot, -1) == tail(a.long1$plot, -1), NA))
#  plot variable value maxS
#4    A       pe   0.7    1
#1    A        s   0.3    0
#2    B        s   0.7    1
#5    B       pe   0.3    0
#3    C        s   0.6    1
#6    C       pe   0.4   NA
```

Remember, vectorization is usually preferable over loops in R. Here I create two vectors by removing the  last and first element from `plot` and then compare these. Then I need to add one `NA` value, because there is no subsequent value to the last value of `plot`. `as.numeric` coerces `TRUE`/`FALSE` to 0/1.